# How to remove title bar and operate in full screen mode?

Tags: android

I have tried to remove the title bar using the code below. But it doesnt work and it still shows the title bar.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

i even tried changing the theme in the mainfest file as follows.But the app stops working saying " Unfortunately myApp has stopped working".

`<activity android:name="..."
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">`

Comment: What do the logs say?

Answer (score 1):

Do this before calling setContentView()

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
//Remove notification bar
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```